# About the kernel of the structure map of a morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, let $\mathcal{K}$ be the kernel of the structure map $\mathcal{O}_Y\to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$. Do we have

> $$\mathrm{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathcal{K})=\overline{f(X)}?$$

Recall that the support of a sheaf (of abelian groups) is the set of points at which the stalk of that sheaf is nonzero.

I can prove $\subset$ as follows: If $y\in Y$ is in the support, then $(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_y\neq 0$ (since the image of $1$ is $1$), so for any open neighborhood $V$ of $y$, we have $\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}V)\neq 0$, so $f^{-1}V\neq \emptyset$, thus $y\in \overline{f(X)}$. How about the convese? As $\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathcal{K}$ is of finite type, the support is closed, so one possible way is to show $f(X)\subset\mathrm{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathcal{K})$.

Somebody told me it's always true but you can add some mild conditions if you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can prove "=" in one stroke (without extra assumption), in detail as follows: the key observation is that any ring hom maps $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$, and for the structure sheaf of a scheme $X\neq \emptyset$, we have $1\neq 0\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U)\neq 0\Leftrightarrow U\neq \emptyset$. Thus
$$y\in \mathrm{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathcal{K})\Leftrightarrow (\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathcal{K})_y\neq 0\Leftrightarrow (f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_y\neq 0\Leftrightarrow 1\neq 0\in(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_y\Leftrightarrow 1\neq 0\in(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)(V), \forall V\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}V)\neq 0, \forall V\Leftrightarrow f^{-1}V\neq \emptyset, \forall V\Leftrightarrow V\cap f(X)\neq \emptyset, \forall V\Leftrightarrow y\in \overline{f(X)},$$
where $\forall V$ means for all open neighborhoods $V$ of $y$ in $Y$; the 2nd $\Leftrightarrow$ is because we have an injective ring hom $(\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathcal{K})_y\rightarrow(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_y$; the 4th $\Leftrightarrow$ is because the stalk is a filtred colimit over all open neighborhoods. Thus
$$\mathrm{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathcal{K})=\overline{f(X)}.$$

**Edit**:
According to the answer and comments below, the stated result is actually true for all morphisms of *locally ringed spaces* (but *not* for morphisms of ringed spaces), with the same argument.

Comment: If you find an unreasonable point, please make a comment.

Comment: I have a question. Why the 2nd $\Leftarrow$ is true?

Comment: For a injective ring homomorphism $f : A\to B$, although $B\neq 0 $, is there a possibility that $A =0$?

Comment: @Plantation Since the structure map $\mathcal{O}_Y\to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is a morphism of sheaves of rings, $0$ goes to $0$ and $1$ goes to $1$. If $0\ne 1$ in the target, then same holds in the source.

Comment: Some confusion. You mean, $(\mathcal{O}_Y)_y \to (f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X)_y$ sends $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$? And if $0 \neq 1 \in (f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X)_y $  and $0=(\mathcal{O}/\mathcal{K})_y$, how can we deduce contradiction..?

Comment: And I wondering also that why 4 th $\Rightarrow$ is true. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $Y$. Then $1 \in \mathcal{F}_y$ is defined as the class $[(V, 1)]$ for some neighborhodd $y \in V$ and $1 \in \mathcal{F}(V)$. And..although $ 0\neq 1 \in \mathcal{F}_y$, is there a possibility of existence of some neighborhood $ y\in V' \subset Y$ such that $\mathcal{F}(V')$ is zero??

Comment: O.K. For the first question, I think that I understand. Let $f : A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism. $f$ sends $0_A$ to $0_B$ and sends $1_A$ to $1_B$. If $B$ is not zero, then $0_B \neq 1_B$. And if $A$ is zero, then $0_A = 1_A$. But in this case it contradicts to that $f$ is a function!

Comment: So remaining question is, why 4th $\Rightarrow$ is true ~And it seems that it can be proved by the similar argument as above. (?) Thank you.

Comment: @Plantation That's very simple from definition of colimit: if two elements are equal somewhere, they are equal in the colimit.

Comment: O.K. I see. Thank you.~~

Comment: This is not true without additional conditions - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615949/scheme-theoretic-image-hartshorne-ex-ii-3-11-d/3875738#3875738) for an example where the support of $\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathcal{K}$ is strictly greater than $\overline{f(X)}$.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry, can you be precise about the "additional conditions" (maybe qc)? Maybe can you tell anything wrong in the above argument?

Comment: @Lao-tzu sorry, I thought I linked an answer where I explained the additional conditions. You need either quasi-compactness of the morphism or that the source is reduced - see some discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892303/how-can-one-describe-the-closure-of-the-image-of-a-morphism-of-schemes/3892358#3892358). I don't immediately see the problem in your argument, but it's also formatted in a way that is really difficult for me to read and I haven't had the time between my other commitments today to dissect it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to see this if we assume that $f$ is quasi-compact:

First note that the statement is true if both $X,Y$ are affine, say $X=\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. Indeed in this case, we have that $\overline{f(X)} = V(I)$, where $I$ is the kernel of the map $A\rightarrow B$. Of course here we have that $\operatorname{Supp}(A/I) = V(I)$.

Now let's suppose that $f$ is quasi-compact. We can assume that $Y$ is affine. Since $f$ is quasi-compact, we can cover $X$ by finitely many affine opens $U_i$, and we have that $\overline{f(X)} = \overline{ \bigcup_i f(U_i) } = \bigcup_i \overline{f(U_i)}$ (we used finiteness for the last equality).

By the above, we have that $\overline{f(U_i)} = \operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Y/K_{U_i})$, where $K_{U_i}$ is the kernel of the map $\mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow (f|_{U_i})_* \mathcal{O}_{U_i}$. We claim that $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Y/K_{U_i}) \subseteq \operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Y/K_X)$, where $K_X$ is the kernel of the map $\mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow f_* \mathcal{O}_X$. This follows from the fact that $K_X \subseteq K_{U_i}$.

This implies that $\overline{f(X)} \subseteq \operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Y/K_X)$.

Comment: Don't you need $Y$ compact for the reduction to $Y$ affine to work?

Comment: @user347489 ah I think you're right

Comment: I don't see why one needs $Y$ affine for the reduction to work - we have $\overline{f(X)}^X \cap U = \overline{U \cap f(X)}^U$ (here I use a supscript to indicate in which ambient space the closure is taken), so the whole statement is local on $Y$.

Possibly interesting sidenote: Under your assumptions, you can replace $X$ by $\coprod U_i$ without changing $K$. Then your morphism becomes qcqs, so $f_* O_X$ and thus $K$ is quasi-coherent, which gives a scheme structure on $\overline{f(X)}$, known as scheme-theoretic image.

Comment: @JohannHaas The statement is local on $Y$, hence I can assume that $Y$ is affine. If you're asking if this whole thing is necessary - then I suppose not - see OP's answer.

Comment: @loch Indeed. I just wanted to correct the confusion between you and user347389. I still think your argument has some merit: The OP's is more general and works for arbitrary locally ringed spaces; but yours can be extended to obtain a refinement of the OP's statement involving subscheme structures.

Comment: @JohannHaas My own answer isn't true for arbitrary locally ringed spaces I guess, at least one key observation—for the structure sheaf of a scheme $X\neq \emptyset$, $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\neq 0\Leftrightarrow U\neq \emptyset$—need not be true for arbitrary locally ringed spaces; since I think for a locally ringed spaces $X$, $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=0$ for some $U\neq \emptyset$ is allowed.

Comment: @Lao-tzu The zero ring does not have a unique maximal ideal, so it isn't a local ring. So the equivalence is actually true for all locally ringed spaces (but not for all ringed spaces)

Comment: @Johann Haas That's quite good!

Comment: Can I ask question? Why we may assume that $Y$ is affine? In general, since $f$ is quasi-compact, let's cover $Y$ by affine open subsets $\{ U_i \}$ such that each $f^{-1}(U_i)$ are quasi-compact. Then $f|_{f^{-1}(U_i)}^{U_i} : f^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i$ are also quasi-compact. Now, for each i, let $K_i :=\operatorname{ker}( f|_{f^{-1}(U_i)}^{U_i})^{\flat} : \mathcal{O}_Y|_{U_i} \to (f|_{f^{-1}(U_i)}^{U_i})_{*}\mathcal{O}_X|_{f^{-1}(U_i)}$. Then by the reduction assumption, $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_{U_{i}}/K_i)=\overline{f(f^{-1}(U_i))}^{U_i}=\overline{f(X) \cap U_i}^{U_i}$.

Comment: My question is, $\bigcup_i(\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_{U_i}/K_i) = \operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_Y/K)$?